# Iterator hasNext() Method

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

Why do we implement hasNext method as

```
public boolean hasNext() {
            if(current != null) 
                return true;
            return false;
}
```

instead of

```
public boolean hasNext() {
            if(current.getNext() != null) 
                return true;
            return false;
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the rest of the iterator implementation.  That's not necessarily the appropriate approach for all iterators.  (That said, it's not uncommon for the iterator to look like that, because "current" is the next element to be returned.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who *we* is but consider the following.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
            if(current != null) 
                return true;
            return false;
}
```

In the previous case, `next()` would return the value and update current.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
            if(current.getNext() != null) 
                return true;
            return false;
}
```

In this case, if `getNext()` is null, you still need to return the current value (e.g. `current.getValue()`) so you would miss the last one.

But keep in mind that `hasNext()` and `next()` don't work in isolation of each other.  So it depends on how both are implemented as to whether either method makes sense.